# How can i responsive anything with position absolute?

Tags: css, position

When i do some design with position absolute, the content i created with position absolute is moving every break point when i resize the browser.So how to use position absolute properly that it always remain his place in every device or every break point??

Answer (score 2):

Try for example:

`Position: absolute;`

And give as per requirement

```
left:20%; right:20%; top:20% bottom:20%; width:80%;
```

Comment: patil, Welcome to StackOverflow. please explain your code and tell us how your code solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

position: fixed;

since fixed means its relative to the viewport, which means it always stays in the same place even if the page is scrolled.

Answer (score 0):

You should give your code so we can control, but fixed might resolve your problem, the bar will be stuck at the top of the page